# Why is invoke-command and new-pssession not working?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have no idea why this isn't working. Any ideas? I honestly don't know what else I can try.

I plan to add it to a script that prompts the user for a computername / domain creds but I can't get it to work in a shell window for starters.

Here's the line:

```
Invoke-Command -Session New-PSSession -ComputerName server001 -ScriptBlock {shutdown.exe /r -t 0}
```

Here's the error:

```
Invoke-Command : Cannot bind parameter 'Session'. Cannot convert the "New-PSSession" value of type "System.String" to
type "System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession".
At line:1 char:25
+ Invoke-Command -Session New-PSSession -ComputerName server001 -Scrip ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Sorry for not having anything further to add to this but I'm still trying to learn PowerShell and need guidance.

Comment: `-Session New-PSSession -ComputerName server001` --> `-Session (New-PSSession -ComputerName server001)`

Comment: You're a star thank you Mathias! The simplest things always need pointing out to me I appreciate that. Would you like to add this as your answer so I can close the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates, the `-Session` parameter accepts arguments of type `PSSession` - and to create such an object we need to *invoke* `New-PSSession` (not just pass it's *name* as an argument):

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName computer01
Invoke-Command -Session $session { ... }
```

If you don't plan on reusing the session later, you can simply pass the computer name directly to `Invoke-Command`, it'll handle session management for you implicitly:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer01 { ... }
```